# Excel - Separate formula for calculating different rates based on hours discussion

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

[image]

I am trying to calculate my hours based on the rate those hours were worked.
Right now my formula looks like:

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(D6,"dddd")=H4,J14>=48,O12="Yes"),D14*(G3*2),IF(AND(TEXT(D6,"dddd")=G4,J14>40),D14*(G3*1.5),G3*D14))
```

I know that D14 is not the proper cell to use, just what I had came up with to partially get this working.

What I need is to add if over 8 hours calculate at this rate, if day 1 off calculate it all at 1.5 and if second day off calculate it at 2x rate.  the equation I stated above is a working if for the days off part, i just need help with the rate part.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, from here i can figure out what equation I'll need for the false.

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(E6,"dddd")=H4,J14>=48,O12="Yes"),E14*(G3*2),IF(AND(TEXT(E6,"dddd")=G4,J14>40),E14*(G3*1.5),IF((E10-E7+(E10<E7)-(E9-E8))*24>8,(E11*G3)+(E12*(G3*1.5)),FALSE)))
```